# Handsontable: Update column setting, but exclude the first row

Tags: javascript, formatting, handsontable

We have an operation in our Hands on table app that assigns a format to columns via a drop down as demonstrated here: 
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-custom-renderers.html#page-dropdown

When a new format is picked, we apply the formatting to the column.

```
columns[i].type = type;
instance.updateSettings({columns: columns});
```

What I need to do is exclude the first row from this type of column update as it is a static text field which should not be changed. Is there an example of this available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `cells` option takes precedence over `columns`. So what you could do is set `cells` to the following:

```
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
    var cellProperties;

    if (row === 0) {
        cellProperties = {
            type: 'text' // force text type for first row
        };

        return cellProperties;
    }
}
```

What this will do is set a type to the first row. Now when you update `columns`, it won't apply to the first row because `cells` is taking precedence.

Comment: This was the fix. Just checking the first row. Pretty simple but it works like a charm. Thanks!